# What is making this Python code so slow? How can I modify it to run faster?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, loops, data-analysis

I am writing a program in Python for a data analytics project involving advertisement performance data matched to advertisement characteristics aimed at identifying high performing groups of ads that share n similar characteristics. The dataset I am using has individual ads as rows, and characteristic, summary, and performance data as columns. Below is my current code - the actual dataset I am using has 51 columns, 4 are excluded, so it is running with 47 C 4, or 178365 iterations in the outer loop.

Currently, this code takes ~2 hours to execute. I know that nested for loops can be the source of such a problem, but I do not know why it is taking **so** long to run, and am not sure **how** I can modify the inner/outer for loops to improve performance. Any feedback on either of these topics would be greatly appreciated.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Identify Clusters of Rows (Ads) that have a KPI value above a certain threshold
def set_groups(df, n):
    """This function takes a dataframe and a number n, and returns a list of lists. Each list is a group of n columns.
    The list of lists will hold all size n combinations of the columns in the dataframe.
    """
    # Create a list of all relevant column names
    columns = list(df.columns[4:]) # exclude first 4 summary columns
    # Create a list of lists, where each list is a group of n columns
    groups = []
    vals_lst = list(map(list, itertools.product([True, False], repeat=n))) # Create a list of all possible combinations of 0s and 1s
    for comb in itertools.combinations(columns, n): # itertools.combinations returns a list of tuples
        groups.append([comb, vals_lst])
    groups = np.array(groups,dtype=object)
    return groups  # len(groups) = len(columns(df)) choose n

def identify_clusters(df, KPI, KPI_threshhold, max_size, min_size, groups):
    """
    This function takes in a dataframe, a KPI, a threshhold value, a max and min size, and a list of lists of groupings.
    The function will identify groups of rows in the dataframe that have the same values for each column in each list of groupings.
    The function will return a list of lists with each list of groups, the values list, and the ad_ids in the cluster.
    """
    # Create a dictionary to hold the results
    output = []
    # Iterate through each list of groups
    for group in groups:
        for vals_lst in group[1]:  # for each pair of groups and associated value matrices
            # Create a temporary dataframe to hold the group of rows with matching values for columns in group
            temp_df = df
            for i in range(len(group[0])):
                temp_df = temp_df[(temp_df[group[0][i]] == vals_lst[i])]  # reduce the temp_df to only rows that match the values in vals_lst for each combination of values
            if temp_df[KPI].mean() > KPI_threshhold:  # if the mean of the KPI for the temp_df is above the threshhold
                output.append([group, vals_lst, temp_df['ad_id'].values])  # append the group, vals_lst, and ad_ids to the output list
    print(output)
    return output

## Main
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name='name')
groups = set_groups(df, 4)
print(len(groups))
identify_clusters(df, 'KPI_var', 0.0015, 6, 4, groups)
```

Any insight into why the code is taking such a long time to run, and/or any advice on improving the performance of this code would be extremely helpful.

Comment: For me at least it is not 100% clear what you are trying to do. A [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example will increase the chance of getting an answer.

Comment: @Alex, I am trying to create a list of filtered dataframes, where each filtered dataframe only contains rows that share the same values for all columns in all possible combinations of groups of columns, and combinations of values for those columns. The returned dataframes will each share the same values for certain columns, but also have a mean KPI over a given threshhold. The concept is to identify clusters of high performing ads that share certain characteristics. I will try to create a reproducible example and post again.

Comment: hi James: immediately i can tell you that you are iterating over a dataframe. This should set alarm bells ringing. There will invariably be a vectorised method that will be orders of magnitude faster:  https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pandas-vectorization/

Answer (score 1):

I think your biggest issue is the lines:

```
temp_df = df
for i in range(len(group[0])):
    temp_df = temp_df[(temp_df[group[0][i]] == vals_lst[i])]
```

You're filtering the entire dataframe while I think you're only actually interested in the KPI and `ad_id` columns. You could instead create a rolling mask, something like

```
mask = pd.Series(True, index=df.index)
for i in range(len(group[0])):
    mask = mask & (temp_df[group[0][i]] == vals_lst[i])]
```

You can then access your subsets something like `df[mask][KPI].mean()` and `df[mask]['ad_id'].values`. If you do this, you will avoid copying a huge amount of data on every iteration.

I would also be tempted to simplify the code a little, for example I believe `vals_lst = list(map(list, itertools.product([True, False], repeat=n)))` is the same for each group, so I would probably calculate it once and hold it as a stand alone variable rather than add it to every group; this would clean up the `group[0]`, `group[1]` and `group[0][i]` references which were a little hard to track on first reading the code.

Looking at the change from iterative filtering to tracking a mask, the mask approach always to perform better, but the gap increases with data size. With 10000 rows the gaps are:

| Method | Time | Relative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Original | 2.900383699918166 | 2.8098094911581533 |
| Using Mask | 1.03223499993328 | 1.0 |

with the following test code:

```py
import random, timeit
import pandas as pd

random.seed(1)
iterations = 1000

data = {hex(i): [random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(10000)] for i in range(52)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

kpi_col = hex(1)

# test group of columns with desired values
group = (
    (hex(5), 1),
    (hex(6), 1),
    (hex(7), 1),
    (hex(8), 1)
)

def method0():
    tmp = df
    for column, value in group:
        tmp = tmp[tmp[column] == value]
    return tmp[kpi_col].mean()

def method1():
    mask = pd.Series(True, df.index)
    for column, value in group:
        mask = mask & (df[column] == value)
    return df[mask][kpi_col].mean()

assert method0() == method1()

t0 = timeit.timeit(lambda: method0(), number=iterations)
t1 = timeit.timeit(lambda: method1(), number=iterations)

tmin = min((t0, t1))

print(f'| Method                                  | Time | Relative      |')
print(f'|------------------                       |----------------------|')
print(f'| Original                                | {t0} | {t0 / tmin}   |')
print(f'| Using Mask                              | {t1} | {t1 / tmin}   |')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In the above lines, the segment 
`temp_df = temp_df[(temp_df[group[0][i]] == vals_lst[i])]`
Is intended to filter the dataframe for each column in the first element of group, which is a list of columns. vals_lst in this case refers to a combination of values for the given groups stored in `group[0] for group in groups`. So in effect in those lines I am trying to filter the dataframe for rows where each column in group[0], so group[0][i] matches the corresponding value in all vals_lst combinations, so vals_lst[i] for vals_lst in the outer loop. Agree on vals_lst point.

Comment: Regarding "If you do this, you will avoid copying a huge amount of data on every iteration.": I don't think the data is copied here.

Comment: As I understand it it, you're repeatedly filtering down `temp_df`. The problem with this is you're creating a new set of data corresponding to the filter in each iteration; for example, if for any iteration of `temp_df` you call `temp_df['ad_id'].values` it will return a numpy array with the data. That array is created when you filter the dataframe. What I'm suggested is rather than creating the filtered copy of the dataframe, just track the rows which are are still interested in. This way, you only two new Series objects on each iteration.